# Awesome Bootstrap Checkboxes for Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ and I wanted to style my checkboxes (http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/demo/) ... BUT for some reason I can't change it to the required html structure.

The default Bootstrap Multiselect HTML:

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input value="AD" type="checkbox"> Andorra (AD)
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
```

That's how it should be e.g.

```
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
    <li class="active">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="multiselect-0" value="vikings" type="checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox" for="multiselect-0"> Minnesota Vikings</label>
        </div>
    </li>
```

That's how I initialize it:

```
$('.test-select').multiselect({
    templates: { // Use the Awesome Bootstrap Checkbox structure
        li: '<li><div class="checkbox"><label></label></div></li>'
    }   
});
```

That's how I wanted to change the structure:

```
$('.multiselect-container div.checkbox').each(function (index) {

    var id = 'multiselect-' + index,
        $input = $(this).find('input');

    $(this).find('label').attr('for', id);  
    $input.attr('id', id);

    $input.detach();

    $input.prependTo($(this));

    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

I got this from here: http://jsfiddle.net/natearmagost/aznvcLps/ Anyone an idea why it might not be working on my side or an alternative how to do so?

The below solution works, but unfortunately not yet if I load the options via $.ajax get and rebuild the multiselect. Anybody an idea why?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/country.php',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
     $.each(data.data, function (i, item) {
         display = item.display;
         $('.select-country').append('<option value="' + display + '">(' + display + ')</option>');
         //console.log(item)
    });
    $('.select-country').multiselect('rebuild');
}
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like you have conflicts between the Bootstrap-Multiselect CSS and the Awesome Checkbox CSS since they box use the class `.checkbox`. Try changing the Awesome Checkbox class to something else.

**Working Template Structure:**

```
<li>
  <a tabindex="0">
    <div class="aweCheckbox aweCheckbox-danger">
      <label for=""></label>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Based on the default Bootstrap-Multiselect markup, the above template works. Basically just adding the `a` tag to it.

I also had to modify the `.checkbox label` rule to accommodate Bootstrap-Multiselect with the following:

`padding: 0 20px 0 10px; cursor: pointer;`

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').multiselect({
    templates: { // Use the Awesome Bootstrap Checkbox structure
      li: '<li class="checkList"><a tabindex="0"><div class="aweCheckbox aweCheckbox-danger"><label for=""></label></div></a></li>'
    }
  });
  $('.multiselect-container div.aweCheckbox').each(function(index) {

    var id = 'multiselect-' + index,
      $input = $(this).find('input');

    // Associate the label and the input
    $(this).find('label').attr('for', id);
    $input.attr('id', id);

    // Remove the input from the label wrapper
    $input.detach();

    // Place the input back in before the label
    $input.prependTo($(this));

    $(this).click(function(e) {
      // Prevents the click from bubbling up and hiding the dropdown
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.aweCheckbox {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.aweCheckbox label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.aweCheckbox label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.aweCheckbox label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555;
}
.aweCheckbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.aweCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.aweCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f00c";
}
.aweCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:indeterminate + label::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: -16.5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.aweCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  opacity: 0.65;
}
.aweCheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.aweCheckbox.aweCheckbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.aweCheckbox.aweCheckbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.aweCheckbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}
.aweCheckbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff;
}
.aweCheckbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:indeterminate + label::before {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}
.aweCheckbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:indeterminate + label::after {
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type="checkbox"].styled:checked + label:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";
}
input[type="checkbox"] .styled:checked + label::before {
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="checkbox"] .styled:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select name="teams" id="teams" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
      <option value="vikings">Minnesota Vikings</option>
      <option value="packers">Green Bay Packers</option>
      <option value="lions">Detroit Lions</option>
      <option value="bears">Chicago Bears</option>
      <option value="patriots">New England Patriots</option>
      <option value="jets">New York Jets</option>
      <option value="bills">Buffalo Bills</option>
      <option value="dolphins">Miami Dolphins</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome answer vanburen ... working like a charm. many thanks for this.

Comment: Hi vanburen ... if I load the options via $.ajax get and rebuild the multiselect ... the html structure won't change as required. Any idea why so?

Comment: i took an idea --now using bootstrap 4 custom checkbox template...instead of adding custom css.